# Concatenating individual bits in C

Tags: c, append, bit

I have the following situation:

A function F1 generates an output O1 that is N1 bits in size, where N1 will in general not bit a multiple of 8 bits. Another function F2, in turn, generates an output O2 that is N2 bits in size, where N2 may, or may not, be a multiple of 8 bits.

I want to obtain an output string O construct with O2 appended to O1, with the following proviso:

Imagine the N1 % 8 is 3, and the last three bits of N1 are 101. Also imagine that the first eight bits of N2 are 01011111. The sequence of bytes that I would end up with would have the first floor(N1 / 8) bytes from O1, then then 10101011 byte, then bytes will the rest of the N2 bits obtained in N2, starting with the 111 leftover from above.

The thing is, both N1 and N2 can potentially be extremely long numbers - far bigger than the RAM in the host computer. Thus, I would have to store the N1 and N2 bits on hard drive, then perform the concatenation as described above, saving the resulting output O.

I am looking for suggestions on how to carry out the chore above as efficiently as possible, bearing in mind that, like I said, both N1 and N2 can be arbitrarily large. What worries me in particular is the bit shifting that one must carry out on O2.

Comment: Yes, the same operation would have to be performed on every output byte. But that could be a streaming operation with a very small buffer.

Comment: Well, you could perform it on 64 or bits at once, but yeah, if you want to shift all the bits in O2, you will need to shift all the bits in O2. But that's very cheap compared to the I/O needed.

Comment: `both N1 and N2 can potentially be extremely long numbers - far bigger than the RAM in the host computer. Thus, I would have to store the N1 and N2 bits on hard drive,` Thus no matter what magic you do, I/O will be your bottleneck, so invest time and resources in a good hard drive and filesystem configuration.

Comment: Re “Thus, I would have to store the N1 and N2 bits on hard drive, then perform the concatenation as described above, saving the resulting output O”: As you have described it, that is not necessary. F1 simply outputs its bits in groups of eight or multiples thereof as it generates. When it finishes, it has 0-7 bits left. Then, as F2 generates its bits, it includes F1’s leftover bits and continues outputting bits in groups of eight or multiples thereof. At the end, any leftover bits are output. (It is unstated whether the final few bits should be left-aligned or right-aligned.)

Answer (score -1):

Here's a C header file that may have what you are looking for: https://github.com/MorbidlyABeastAtGitHub/gcc-almost-std/blob/main/stdbit.h
It has has the ability to read and write individual bits to variables as well as files.